# Copyright status of blog post containing Stack Overflow answers?

Tags: discussion, blog, legal

I've got an idea for a blog post I want to write which compares different approaches to a problem demonstrated in the answers to a question on the site.

For a specific example: there are so many ways to approach generating powersets in Python, and many are shown here: [How to get all subsets of a set? (powerset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482308/how-to-get-all-subsets-of-a-set-powerset)

What would be the copyright status of a blog post where I shared some of these approaches, using the code samples given in the answers, and discussed their various advantages and disadvantages please?